# SQL needed Microsoft Office Access to determine percentiles for seperate repeating records

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, percentile

I have a chemical plant's database which contains all the samples taken and analyzed over a period of one year. It contains a `Date` (date of the sample taken), `Point` (where the sample was taken), `Report` (what chemical was tested for) and a `Values` (the lab results) field.

The `Points` field has 30 records which are repeated continuously for the duration of 1 year. Each repetition has the same `Date` entry for all the records.

I need to find the 75th and 95th percentile `Values` for *each* of the Points field records for the duration of the year where the `Report` is "Ammonia". 75th Percentile meaning that 75% of the data entries has the percentile value or less.

Best attempt was from:

```
SELECT Point, Max(Values)  
FROM Table  
WHERE Values In(  
SELECT TOP 75 PERCENT Values   
FROM Table  
WHERE Report = "Ammonia"   
ORDER BY Values ASC  
)  
GROUP BY Point;
```

But this gives unexpected results since the result given is the TOP 75% of ALL the data and not per `Point`.

**The final output should be**:

```
Point_1 75th_1
Point_2 75th_2
Point_3 75th_3
...
Point_30 75th_30
```

It should be noted that the data is inconsistent in the manner that some days only 29 or 24 points were sampled and samples were taken every two or three days, never within pattern.

### **Sample Delimited Data**

```
Date;Point;Report;Values
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX1";"Ammonia";10,40
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX1";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX1";"COD";106,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX1";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX1";"MLSS";2856,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX1";"NOX";0,10
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX1";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX1";"PO4";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX2";"Ammonia";11,20
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX2";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX2";"COD";129,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX2";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX2";"MLSS";2834,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX2";"NOX";0,30
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX2";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX2";"PO4";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX3";"Ammonia";10,20
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX3";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX3";"COD";111,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX3";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX3";"MLSS";3128,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX3";"NOX";0,20
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX3";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX3";"PO4";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX4";"Ammonia";10,20
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX4";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX4";"COD";121,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX4";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX4";"MLSS";3358,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX4";"NOX";0,50
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX4";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_ANX4";"PO4";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"Ammonia";0,40
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"COD";56,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"Conductivity";62,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"NOX";4,20
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"PO4";0,10
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"Ammonia";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"COD";48,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"Conductivity";57,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"NOX";4,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"pH";7,20
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"PO4";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"Ammonia";0,70
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"COD";40,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"Conductivity";57,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"NOX";6,10
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"pH";7,30
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"PO4";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL3";"Ammonia";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL3";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL3";"COD";87,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL3";"Conductivity";57,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL3";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL3";"NOX";3,50
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL3";"pH";7,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL3";"PO4";0,20
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"Ammonia";0,10
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"COD";59,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"Conductivity";55,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"NOX";4,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"pH";7,30
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"PO4";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC1";"Ammonia";0,50
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC1";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC1";"COD";56,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC1";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC1";"MLSS";3272,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC1";"NOX";2,30
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC1";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC1";"PO4";6,30
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC2";"Ammonia";3,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC2";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC2";"COD";55,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC2";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC2";"MLSS";2504,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC2";"NOX";1,60
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC2";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC2";"PO4";11,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC3";"Ammonia";0,10
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC3";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC3";"COD";60,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC3";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC3";"MLSS";2818,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC3";"NOX";3,20
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC3";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC3";"PO4";6,50
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC4";"Ammonia";0,40
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC4";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC4";"COD";58,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC4";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC4";"MLSS";2792,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC4";"NOX";3,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC4";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PRIM_REAC4";"PO4";6,10
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST1";"Ammonia";23,10
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST1";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST1";"COD";974,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST1";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST1";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST1";"NOX";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST1";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST1";"PO4";5,60
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST2";"Ammonia";22,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST2";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST2";"COD";1077,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST2";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST2";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST2";"NOX";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST2";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST2";"PO4";5,10
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST3";"Ammonia";20,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST3";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST3";"COD";1099,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST3";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST3";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST3";"NOX";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST3";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST3";"PO4";5,10
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST4";"Ammonia";21,60
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST4";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST4";"COD";1070,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST4";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST4";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST4";"NOX";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST4";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_PST4";"PO4";5,30
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"Ammonia";19,10
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"COD";2270,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"Conductivity";63,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"NOX";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"pH";6,60
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"PO4";5,20
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC1";"Ammonia";0,10
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC1";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC1";"COD";59,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC1";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC1";"MLSS";2802,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC1";"NOX";2,60
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC1";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC1";"PO4";5,70
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC2";"Ammonia";0,10
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC2";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC2";"COD";65,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC2";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC2";"MLSS";2896,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC2";"NOX";3,20
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC2";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC2";"PO4";5,60
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC3";"Ammonia";0,30
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC3";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC3";"COD";64,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC3";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC3";"MLSS";3412,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC3";"NOX";3,70
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC3";"pH";6,90
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC3";"PO4";4,80
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC4";"Ammonia";0,60
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC4";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC4";"COD";66,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC4";"Conductivity";0,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC4";"MLSS";3208,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC4";"NOX";3,10
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC4";"pH";7,00
2013-11-25 00:00:00;"HARTE_SEC_REAC4";"PO4";5,10
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"Ammonia";2,60
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"COD";69,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"Conductivity";74,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"NOX";3,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"pH";7,70
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL_CONT";"PO4";0,50
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"Ammonia";3,90
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"COD";79,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"Conductivity";75,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"NOX";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"pH";7,60
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL1";"PO4";1,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"Ammonia";4,30
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"COD";73,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"Conductivity";73,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"NOX";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"pH";7,50
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL2";"PO4";0,60
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"Ammonia";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"COD";65,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"Conductivity";70,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"NOX";7,90
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"pH";7,60
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_FINAL4";"PO4";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"Ammonia";19,30
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"Chlorides";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"COD";1261,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"Conductivity";81,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"MLSS";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"NOX";0,00
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"pH";6,80
2013-11-26 00:00:00;"HARTE_RAW";"PO4";5,10`
```

Comment: You need to post queries you have tried and need help with....

Comment: and please also provide an example of the table(s) you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved what was needed by implementing the following:

```
SELECT Point, MAX(Values)
FROM Table
WHERE Values IN(
SELECT TOP 75 PERCENT Values
FROM Table dummy
WHERE dummy.Report = "Ammonia"
AND Table.Report=dummy.Report
ORDER BY dummy.Values ASC
)
GROUP BY Point
```